# jQuery UI - drag an item from drop area and drop it back to same drop area - drop event doesn't fired

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, drag-and-drop, jquery-ui-draggable, jquery-ui-droppable

I have number of drop areas $('.drophere') and a storage of draggables $('.dragme').
Each drop area can contain just one dropped item.

You can drop new item over dropped one (replace). You can drag an item from one drop area to other.

If you start drag an item from drop area and decided drop it back to same area - drop event is not fired, thus the dragged item is lost.

Here is simplified code:

```
var draggedData;
$('.drophere').droppable({
  drop: function (event, ui) {
    $(this).attr('data-text', draggedData);
    $(this).draggable('enable');
  }
}).draggable({
  disabled: true,
  helper: "clone",
  start: function (event, ui) {
    draggedData = $(this).attr('data-text');
    $(this).attr('data-text', "").draggable('disable');
  }
});

$('.dragme').draggable({
  helper: "clone",
  start: function (event, ui) {
    draggedData = $(this).attr('data-text');
  }
});
```

Is it some kind of restriction in jQuery UI droppable? Is any way to "forget" the origins of such dragged item? Thank you.

just added: http://jsfiddle.net/gpnpwwbw/

Comment: Rather than "forget the origin" can't you use `stop`?

Comment: It'd be useful if you posted this with some HTML in a jsfiddle

Comment: added jsfiddle. What do you mean - stop ?

Comment: stop is triggered when the item is dropped, no matter where it's dropped. You could check in that function if the item has been dropped elsewhere or not. http://jsfiddle.net/gpnpwwbw/3/

Comment: stop means I have test all dom for possible drop area by myself. I prefer using drop event instead.

Comment: ...with which you aren't able to come up with a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Taking advantage of jQuery Draggables Stop event I came up with the following solution:

```
    var draggedData,
    dropLastDragged
    startPosData = {};

function checkIntersect(posData){
    var left = startPosData.left,
        top = startPosData.top,
        right = startPosData.left+startPosData.width,
        bottom = startPosData.top+startPosData.height,
        cornerLeftPos = posData.left,
        cornerTopPos = posData.top;

        cornerLeftPos += startPosData.width/2;
        cornerTopPos += startPosData.height/2;

    if((cornerLeftPos > left && cornerLeftPos < right) && (cornerTopPos > top && cornerTopPos < bottom)){
        return true;    
    }
    return false;
}

$('.drophere').droppable({
  drop: function (event, ui) {
    dropLastDragged = false;
    $(this).html(draggedData);
    $(this).draggable('enable');
  }
}).draggable({
  disabled: true,
  helper: "clone",
  start: function (event, ui) {
    startPosData.left = ui.offset.left;
    startPosData.width = $(this).width();
    startPosData.top = ui.offset.top;
    startPosData.height = $(this).height();
    draggedData = $(this).html();
    $(this).html('Drop here').draggable('disable');
    dropLastDragged = this;
  },
  stop: function(event, ui) {
    if(dropLastDragged){
        if(checkIntersect(ui.offset)){
            $(dropLastDragged).html(ui.helper.html());
            $(dropLastDragged).draggable('enable');
        }
    }
  }
});

$('.dragme').draggable({
  helper: "clone",
  start: function (event, ui) {
    draggedData = $(this).html();
  }
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/s95bq3yu/2/)

Comment: Sorry, that doesn't helps me - you can't drop the dragged outside of drop area - it always returns back.

Comment: @AlexanderZilber well there is a way you can use positioning to detect if you stopped dragging above the original element or not.  If your interested I can update my answer to account for that too.

Comment: @AlexanderZilber Okay, I updated my answer with the code and updated fiddle.

Comment: Thanks! Not exactly what I was looking for, but it works :)